# getting Json from IBM watson

Tags: python, ibm-watson, tone-analyzer

I am new to python and trying to get Json output from IBM Watson tone analyzer.
Here is what I used from Tone analyzer API reference:

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import ToneAnalyzerV3
tone_analyzer = ToneAnalyzerV3(
   username='YOUR SERVICE USERNAME',
   password='YOUR SERVICE PASSWORD',
   version='2016-05-19')
```

The problem here is when I run the code in python it doesn't seem to find 'watson developer cloud' module (even after I did a `pip install`).

All I am trying to do is pass on a few text files through IBM Watson tone analyzer and get the outputs in CSV format.

I would really appreciate any inputs with this.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to import `ToneAnalyzerV3`. Check this example from the docs.

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import ToneAnalyzerV3


tone_analyzer = ToneAnalyzerV3(
    username='YOUR SERVICE USERNAME',
    password='YOUR SERVICE PASSWORD',
    version='2016-05-19')

print(json.dumps(tone_analyzer.tone(text='I am very happy'), indent=2))
```

Link here - [Tone analyzer](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/watson_developer_cloud/tone_analyzer_v3.py)

**EDIT**

Maybe it is not running due to this.

> Tested  (lightly) on: Python from 2.7 to 3.5-dev (development branch). Python 2.6 is partially supported but generates InsecurePlatformWarnings (and other warnings), which can be ignored.

Maybe the problem is from their side.
Try using `python2.6`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, Unfortunately I keep running into same issue.

Comment: I did check the document and tried to use V3Beta. Not sure if this is because I am using pythong 3.5

Comment: Hey, If you are satisfied by my answer and think its correct please accept my answer.

Comment: I updated this answer to use the GA version of the service. Other than that the answer was correct and it works for me on Python 2.7